# Getting extra values in json while fetching from MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

I am trying to fetch data from ajax call via json and access the data after successful ajax call. For the purpose, I wrote the following code :

```
<?php 
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    require_once('../include/functions.php');

    // session_start();

    if( isset($_POST['bike_id']))
    {
        $rows = array();
        // echo " I am in isset";
        $bike_id = $_POST['bike_id'];
        // $modal_name = $_POST['modal_name'];
        // $json['insertModal'] = false;

        // json_decode($modal_name);
        json_decode($bike_id);

        $result = selectBike_Modal($bike_id);

        while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
        echo json_encode($rows);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "bike_id is not set";
    }
?>
```

Now I want to access it via javascript :

```
$('#choose_bike').on('blur',
    function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
            var bike_id = $('#choose_bike').val();
        //     var modal_name = $('#modal_name').val();
        //     // alert("bike_id is " + bike_id);
            alert("On blur is clicked.");
            if ( bike_id == "Select A Bike")
            {
                $('#defaultError').addClass("alert alert-danger");
                $('#defaultError').text("Please choose a Bike");

            }
            else
            {
                // alert("Bike is : " + bike_id);
                $.ajax(
                {
                    url:'../admin/backend/getModal.php',
                    type:'POST',
                    data: { bike_id: bike_id},
                    dataType:"json",

                    success:function(data)
                    {
                        alert(" i am in success");
                        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                        alert("object is " +obj);
                    },
                    error : function() { console.log(arguments); }
                 }
               );
            }

    });
```

I have two issues :

1. I am not getting anything after :

   alert(" i am in success");

Means the following is not working :

```
 var obj = JSON.parse(data);
 alert("object is " +obj);
```

2. The php response is as follows:

> [{"0":"5","bike_modal_id":"5","1":"shahjahan","bike_modal_name":"shahjahan","2":"30","bike_id":"30"},{"0":"6","bike_modal_id":"6","1":"ram","bike_modal_name":"ram","2":"30","bike_id":"30"}]

I am getting

> "0":"5","bike_modal_id":"5"

extra. 
Please help me to parse the json correctly in javascript and getting only required ajax values.

Edit :

Select bike_model looks like :

```
function selectBike_Modal($bike_id)
    {
        include("connectvars.php");
        $query = "select * from bike_model where bike_id = '$bike_id'";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query)
        or die('error in fetching');

        // if ( mysqli_num_rows($result))
        //  return 0;
        // else
            return $result;
        // if ( () )
        // {
        //  return $result;
        // }
        // else
        // {
        //  return 0;
        // }

    }
```

Comment: Can you please share the code for `selectBike_Modal()`

Comment: Are you getting any error in your browser's web console in developer tools?

Comment: yes, **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o**

Comment: if you specify `dataType:"json"` in your ajax call, `JSON.parse()` in `var obj = JSON.parse(data);` is not needed. [`"json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object. The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown.`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: you are getting duplicates in your response - `"0":"5","bike_modal_id":"5"`, etc - as [`mysqli_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) *Fetch a result row as an associative, a numeric array, or both*, with **both** being the default. You can either change `while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))` to `while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))` or to `while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))` ([`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php))

Comment: @Sean Thank you for helping me. Can you please make it an answer, so that I can accept it. And how can I parse in javascript?

Comment: if you have `dataType:"json"` and your returned data is done with `json_encode()`, you don't need to parse it as it is already an object. You can access it by doing `data[0].bike_modal_id`, etc

Comment: @Sean I googled it and it works fine. Please make an answer.. Again thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue 1
Since you set `dataType:"json"` in your ajax properties, parsing your returned data with `JSON.parse()` is not needed, as your returned data is already an object. You can access the objects by simply doing `data[0].bike_modal_name`.

issue 2
Your issue of duplicate values, ie. `"0":"5","bike_modal_id":"5"` is because by default `mysqli_fetch_array()` fetches a result row both as an associative and a numeric array. You can either change

```
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
```

to

```
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
```

or to

```
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
```